# Shnsplit : Find all cue files, split in flacs in the same output directory

Tags: shell

I have found this command to split my FLAC files into Tracks from a cue file:

```
find . -name "*.cue" -exec sh -c 'exec shnsplit -f "$1" -o flac -d "%a" -t "%n_%p-%a-%t" "${1%.cue}.flac"' _ {} \;
```

It is working flawlessly, the only thing is that the output files are going in the directory from where I am launching the command. Is it possible to tell ***shnsplit*** to output the FLAC tracks in the very same directory the ***.cue*** file was found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-d '%a'` does not expand to the current file folder. The '%' escapes are only available for `-printf`.  Consider updating the command to to use `dirname` on `$1`:

```
find . -name "*.cue" -exec sh -c 'exec shnsplit -f "$1" -o flac -d "$(dirname $1)" -t "%n_%p-%a-%t" "${1%.cue}.flac"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution and sadly shnsplit is not working.shnsplit is returning an error. It is trying to split the file to an odd directory : https://i.imgur.com/kDr7X2z.png

Comment: You did not quote `$1` in `$(dirname $1)`. Do `"$(dirname "$1")"`.

Answer (score 2):

The right command to use is this one :

```
find . -name "*.cue" -exec sh -c 'exec shnsplit -f "$1" -o flac -d "$(dirname "$1")" -t "%n_%p-%a-%t" "${1%.cue}.flac"' _ {} \;
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.